# Byte comparation

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I'm work on a simple Assembly code, but, I got that erro:

> test.asm:30: error: comma, colon or end of line expected

Ok, in the line 30 I have this code:

```
cmp byte ptr [129],0    ;anything in the line segment?
```

OK.. I tried this:

```
mov [direct_segment],ax ;segment for Direct information
cmp byte ptr [ax+4],0    ;anything in the line segment?
```

Ok, but, the error is the same :(

How I can solve this ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`byte ptr` is MASM syntax. With NASM it should simply be `byte`, so your first example should be `cmp byte [129],0`  (see e.g. [this syntax guide](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-gas-nasm/index.html)).